# Stretching background image in UITextField. Is it a bug?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, storyboard

I was trying to add a background image to UITextField through Storyboard, but discovered a strange bug. When I'm trying to change Stretching under the View section of the Attributes inspector, the background image in the textfield does not change at all. I have also tried to do this with .xib file, but got the same result. And also I got the same result in UIButtons.

Try it yourself. Put a textfield into a view controller and add a background image to it and set stretching to `0.5, 0.5, 0, 0` You should get nothing.

So, is it a real bug or I'm doing something wrong?